# Sci-fi short story in which re-cloning people is easier than working on family relationships, written around the time that Dolly was cloned

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read it in my high school biology class years ago when we were learning about genetics and cloning but I don't know if it was part of our curriculum or just a passion of my teacher. I think I remember my teacher saying it had been published around the time Dolly was cloned (1996) but I could be wrong.

The story began with a description of a room and described pictures of a girl with her parents at different ages, i.e. as a child and an adult. Then the story kinda talks about the dynamics of a teenage girl and her parents. I think the girl got into some kind of trouble and her parents were debating re-cloning her or something. The story kinda built up and ended on the fact that the girl was cloned and the parents had gotten through a few clones of their kid before this point.

I'm not too certain about this next part but I think the mother was written to be a bit hysterical since I don't think her daughter did anything crazy for them to consider cloning her (I think she got a tattoo or piercing but this part is so vague I'm not sure) and that might've been the point since it was supposed to be some futuristic scenario when re-cloning is easier than actually working on family relationships. I think the girl's name was Diana or Dolly but I can't confirm.

I read it close to a decade ago and I think I tried to find it at the time (since we weren't allowed to take the scanned sheet of the story home) and I believe I found it in a sci-fi short story textbook or a short story published compilation/journal or something like that.

Comment: It's kinda vague in my head and I was a little too young to fully understand subtext but from what I remember, they didn't really discuss disposal. Also, I don't think the kids would have any kind of speeding up process. I vaguely remember the mother discussing how raising a young kid would be easier than a teenager and wanted to do that again. I also think it was her that pushed the husband to get a new clone baby since she was frustrated with the kid and the husband was conversing back and forth until he agreed and then it ended.

Answer (score 11):

I believe this is "To Cuddle Amy" by Nancy Kress. According to [this link](http://researchscholar.co.in/downloads/96-dr-saravanan-r.pdf), :

> The Campbells had this only daughter, Amy, now fourteen. Her behavior is wild and
> beyond control. The police had come to warn too.

and eventually:

> “I’ll throw her out tonight,” he told Allison, “and call the clinic in the
> morning.”

I originally read this in
[Years best SF #6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0061020559)

Comment: Yes, I have that anthology and this is definitely the story. Damn, you beat me to it :-)

Comment: I think that's it! Thank you so much!